# Undefined is not an object error using Expo and Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm using Expo to build a ReactNative app and am trying to access data from a Firebase database.

I'm trying to do:

```
componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('/AppUrl/TestData').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.val()) {
            console.log(snapshot);
        }
    });
}
```

But I'm receiving the error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.firebase.database')

Am I doing something incorrectly?

I've initialized firebase in my App.js file using the code below.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = { loggedIn: null }

    componentWillMount() {
      firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'AIZaSyCBhrmSussrunKQCjXF3efalxnpUNXBpeI',
        authDomain: 'AppUrl.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://AppUrl.firebaseio.com',
        projectId: 'AppUrl',
        storageBucket: 'AppUrl.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '800845709365'
    });
```

Comment: Have you initialised firebase in your app? Please provide this code if you have

Comment: Yes, it's on my laptop at home, so I will update the question to include it when I get back.

Comment: @RyanTurnbull sorry, just added.

Comment: Have you imported firebase to your child class? I'd recommend passing through a firebase prop, and then accessing it via `this.props.firebaseApp.database()...` , this is what they recommend to do

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks will try. My child class is a Screen since I'm using react native navigation. This would mean that I create a firebase prop in the App.js and how would I pass it to the screen? Or do I create the prop in the screen?

Comment: `firebase.initializeApp` returns an app variable so you can assign it, like `var firebaseApp = firebase.intitialiseApp(config);` and then simply pass this as a prop to your screen component, and access it via `this.props.firebaseApp`

Answer (score 0):

For those who might stumble into this; I had the same error when I was referencing the wrong ID .. if you are referencing the root of your data in the firebase database then simply leave the reference empty.

```
firebase.database().ref()
.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```